# Updated man page for ifconfig in GNU/Linux systems.

Tags: man, ifconfig

I've always had the compulsion of checking man page for system-specific usages, and the one for ifconfig on Ubuntu Kylin is just too confusing.

What I'm trying to do is to add additional IPv4 addresses to my virtual machine Ethernet interface, where as the man page for the add subcommand says:

> add address/prefixlen
>
> Add an IPv6 address to an interface.

I suppose this cannot be the only problem with net-tools man page on Linux. So I want to know:

1. Where is the updated net-tools maintained? By each distribution or some specific someone else?
2. Where can one find the up-to-date documents for net-tools?

Comment: There are far too many combinations of options to list *all* of them, so each is described individually and the user is expected to use the ones they need.

Comment: What do you mean with "additional"? Do you mean another IP address for the same interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the page of the net-tools project:

- http://net-tools.sourceforge.net/

It includes documentation for all of the commands in the net-tools package. Here is the man-page for `ifconfig`:

- http://net-tools.sourceforge.net/man/ifconfig.8.html

In order to add an additional IPv4 address to a network interface you would use a command such as the following:

```
ifconfig interface address
```

For example, in order to assign the address `192.168.1.1` to the `eth0` interface you would run:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1
```

Typically you would also supply a network mask corresponding to the desired subnetwork, e.g.:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Also note that net-tools is widely considered to be deprecated. Most people recommend using the [iproute2](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2) suite instead. For further discussion on the state of net-tools see the following ServerFault post:

- [Where is the statement of deprecation of ifconfig (on linux)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/633087/where-is-the-statement-of-deprecation-of-ifconfig-on-linux)